# EventEmitters how to track upload progress? value changes?

Tags: angular, file-upload, eventemitter

Heyy peeps, i've been using [ngx-uploader](https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader) in angular2, in response i'm sending file name thats generated on backend. Response is only sent when file is fully uploaded. So how could i track uploading process which is done by event emitter and looks like this:

```
  files: UploadFile[];
  uploadInput: EventEmitter<UploadInput>;

      startUpload(): void {
        const event: UploadInput = {
          type: 'uploadFile',
          url: 'http://localhost:3030/upload/quality-docs',
          method: 'POST',
          file: this.files[this.files.length - 1],
        };


        this.uploadInput.emit(event);
      }
```

Inside of event.file is percentage value of progress, how do i listen/track it. So when its 100, to do something (get value of name in response)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while i found right way to do this.. in the docs 'readme' there is method called  onUploadOutput(output: UploadOutput): void {} in there u need just to add another if statement which would look like

```
else if(output.type === 'done') { whatever u wanna do}
```

So usually there's attribute that's being changed depending of the stage. So to know the stage of emitter, u just gotta check value of that property. And yea in this case there also was percentage attribute.